# How to remove an item for a OR'd enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like:

```
public enum Blah
{
    RED = 2,
    BLUE = 4,
    GREEN = 8,
    YELLOW = 16
}

Blah colors = Blah.RED | Blah.BLUE | Blah.YELLOW;
```

How could I remove the color blue from the variable colors?

Comment: Small note: a bitwise enum in C# should get the [Flags] attribute above it.

Comment: @Nyerguds, could you explain why it should get the attribute?

Comment: It gives better IntelliSense support while debugging, because it recognises unknown enum values as combinations of existing values.

Comment: It also provides a more meaningful `.ToString()` value. e.g. `RED, BLUE, YELLOW` rather than `22`.

Answer (score 428, accepted):

You need to `&` it with the `~` (complement) of 'BLUE'.

The complement operator essentially reverses or 'flips' all bits for the given data type.  As such, if you use the `AND` operator (`&`) with some value (let's call that value 'X') and the complement of one or more set bits (let's call those bits `Q` and their complement `~Q`), the statement `X & ~Q` clears any bits that were set in `Q` from `X` and returns the result.

So to remove or clear the `BLUE` bits, you use the following statement:

```
colorsWithoutBlue = colors & ~Blah.BLUE
colors &= ~Blah.BLUE // This one removes the bit from 'colors' itself
```

You can also specify multiple bits to clear, as follows:

```
colorsWithoutBlueOrRed = colors & ~(Blah.BLUE | Blah.RED)
colors &= ~(Blah.BLUE | Blah.RED) // This one removes both bits from 'colors' itself
```

or alternately...

```
colorsWithoutBlueOrRed = colors & ~Blah.BLUE & ~Blah.RED
colors &= ~Blah.BLUE & ~Blah.RED // This one removes both bits from 'colors' itself
```

So to summarize:

- `X | Q` sets bit(s) `Q`
- `X & ~Q` clears bit(s) `Q`
- `~X` flips/inverts all bits in `X`

Answer (score 59):

The other answers are correct, but to specifically remove blue from the above you would write:

```
colors &= ~Blah.BLUE;
```

Answer (score 12):

`And not` it...............................

```
Blah.RED | Blah.YELLOW == 
   (Blah.RED | Blah.BLUE | Blah.YELLOW) & ~Blah.BLUE;
```

Answer (score 7):

Thought this might be useful for other people that stumbled here like me.

Be careful how you handle any enum values that you might set to have a value == 0 (sometimes it can be helpful to have a Unknown or Idle state for an enum). It causes problems when relying on these bit manipulation operations.

Also when you have enum values that are combinations of other power of 2 values, e.g.

```
public enum Colour
{
    None = 0,  // default value
    RED = 2,
    BLUE = 4,
    GREEN = 8,
    YELLOW = 16,
    Orange = 18  // Combined value of RED and YELLOW
}
```

In these cases an extension method such as this might come in handy:

```
public static Colour UnSet(this Colour states, Colour state)
{
    if ((int)states == 0)
        return states;

    if (states == state)
        return Colour.None;

    return states & ~state;
}
```

And also the equivilent IsSet method that handles the combined values (albeit in a bit of a hacky way)

```
public static bool IsSet(this Colour states, Colour state)
{
    // By default if not OR'd
    if (states == state)
        return true;

    // Combined: One or more bits need to be set
    if( state == Colour.Orange )
        return 0 != (int)(states & state);

    // Non-combined: all bits need to be set
    return (states & state) == state;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the simpler solution is to avoid using 0 as a flag. I typically set up flag enums like [this](https://hastebin.com/futuwetipo.swift). I don't see how you benefit from specifying a state with a value of 0. After all, the whole point is that you can concern yourself with the programmer-friendly names (`Red, Blue, Green`) rather than the underlying values, yeah?

Comment: Having a `none` or `unknown` or `unset` entry with value == 0 is in many cases a good thing as you can't always assume that a particular value is the default set, e.g. if you only have Red, Blue and Green are you going to have Red as the default value (e.g. the value that the enum has when it is created or the user has not modified it?)

Comment: Can't you just have Unset = 1 and use `1, 2, 4, 8` as your values? If you need a default value, that's what default constructors are for, right? I like to keep things as explicit as possible for the sake of readability, and relying on an enum to default to `default(int)` (`0`) when not given a value, despite being information presumably known by any developer, is too sneaky for my tastes anyway. Edit: Oh wait, would making Unset = 0 prevent something from being `Unset | Blue`?

Comment: You're on the right track in your edit Sinjai, keeping the unset value == 0 actually solves a few problems. One being what you mentioned and another one being if you unset all enum values then you don't need a special case for "Unset" if it is set to zero. (e.g. if you `Red & ~Red` then you end up with zero you would then have to have code to check for this case and explicitly assign the `Unset` value)

Comment: Gotcha. Do you often find yourself dealing with unset flags?

Comment: Whenever I'm working on consuming data from a user or external source or working on anything related to a UI this eventually pops up. You often need to know when the value has not been set by the user or the data source reports corrupt or missing data (you may not want to assign defaults in all cases if data is missing)

Comment: I know this is old but for your Unset method if `states == 0` then `states & ~state == states` so your first branch is not needed. Likewise if `states == state` then `states & ~state == Colour.None` so your second branch is not needed and you can just return `states & ~state`...

Comment: Don't do all this. The accepted answer is sufficient, even when `None`. `states & ~state;` covers all cases correctly. That is the only line needed. 1) When `states` is `0`, the result is always `0`. 2) When `state` is `0`, there is nothing to clear; the result is unchanged. 3) When `state` contains multiple bits, the formula still does the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

To simplify the flag enum and make it may be better to read by avoiding multiples, we can use bit shifting. 
(From a good article [Ending the Great Debate on Enum Flags](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396851/Ending-the-Great-Debate-on-Enum-Flags))

```
[FLAG]
Enum Blah
{
   RED = 1,
   BLUE = 1 << 1,
   GREEN = 1 << 2,
   YELLOW = 1 << 3
}
```

and also to clear all bits

```
private static void ClearAllBits()
{
    colors = colors & ~colors;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about xor(^)?

Given that the FLAG you are trying to remove is there, it will work.. if not, you will have to use an &.

```
public enum Colour
{
    None = 0,  // default value
    RED = 2,
    BLUE = 4,
    GREEN = 8,
    YELLOW = 16,
    Orange = 18  // Combined value of RED and YELLOW
}

colors = (colors ^ Colour.RED) & colors;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
colors &= ~Blah.RED;
```

Answer (score 3):

To toggle the flag, you can use the duckface operator, you don't have to invert bits with ~

```cs
color ^= Color.Red; // unset Color.Red
```

or

```cs
color ^= (Color.Red | Color.Blue); // toggle both Red and Blue
```

However, this toggles the flag instead of clearing it.

Edit for correctness, as mentioned by @daniil-palii

Comment: ^ operator not removes flag but toggles it. If flag wasn't added it became added