# Set flags enum conditionally

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

I have an enum defined as follows

```
 [Flags]
public enum Roles
{
    [Descriptor("owner", "TheProficientLab representative")]
    OWNER = 0,

    [Descriptor("administrator", "Sets up users, questions, modules and reviews training and competency")]
    ADMIN = 1,

    [Descriptor("trainer", "Completes and submits training session with trainee")]
    TRAINER = 2,

    [Descriptor("trainee", "Completes training session with trainer")]
    TRAINEE = 3,

    [Descriptor("assessor", "Evaluates and submits competency assessments")]
    ASSESSOR = 4,

    [Descriptor("director or designee", "Approves training and competency")]
    DIRECTOR = 5
}
```

It is then a property in a class

`public Common.Constants.Role.Roles Roles { get; set; }`

How would I set that enum to multiple flags based on condition

Essentially I am looking for something like this

```
if (something)
   Item.Roles += Roles.ADMIN
if (something else)
   Item.Roles += Roles.ASSESSOR
```

Is there a `+=` and `-=` equivalents in bitwise world?

Comment: See the [Flags Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0). Your enum values need to be powers of 2, as in 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful. Doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: Sure it does; look in those docs. You'd use the `|` (bitwise OR operation) to combine your fields, as in: `Item.Roles = Item.Roles | Roles.ADMIN;`

Comment: Ah I see now. Didn't occur to me for some reason that Item.Roles and Role enum is the same thing so `|` would work like `+=`. Thanks, add it as answer please I'll mark it.

Comment: Is there a way to `-=` ?

Comment: Sure. To remove: `Item.Roles &= ~Roles.ADMIN; // revoke admin privileges`. See [this PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4778181/2330053) for some more examples.

Comment: I would avoid using Enum Flags for that...

Comment: Why? (extra chars for the comment limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Idle_Mind's answer in the comments

`Item.Roles |= Role.ADMIN` to add

`ItemRoles &= ~Role.ADMIN` to remove

and the values need to be powers of 2 per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0)